# Creating functional classes in Django that provide deployment pipeline functionality

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am learning Django, so please correct any issues with my way of thinking here.
To start, I am using the Django Rest framework and I'm not interested in just creating a list of items, which is all that I can find examples of on the entire Internet...

I will have some pretty large functional classes that will POST and GET data to and from a pipeline server (TFS to be specific) and obviously, I'll need to insert this logic into a file within my `app`, I'm not just displaying things from my database here.

So, my question is, where does this go within my app? my understanding is that the "Django way" is to keep `models` thick.. does that mean that all code logic to make requests and interact with the pipeline server should end up in my `models.py`?

It's kinda frustrating that everyone else seems to just be listing furniture or some other sales item from their database. Which does not really help me very much... I need to know what a very large web app would look like (one that has a lot of logic and not just a stupid list of red and blue chairs).